# Is it impossible to install windows 7 via boot camp in a lion based macbook air?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have installed windows xp/vista through bootcamp with snow leopard (boot camp 3.x) several times. After a fresh installation of lion on my macbook air, something has changed.

With boot camp 4.0, I cannot create a bootcamp partition for windows 7 without external cd-rom, which would not occur with snow leopard. I tried to use usb stick and virtual windows 7 cd on the usb stick however, both not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible.

1. Create a partition for Windows.
2. Get the [Windows 7 USB DVD download tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe).  Create a bootable USB installer.
3. Boot from the USB stick and install Windows to the partition you made.

If you already tried the above, what error do you get?